# How to choose from choices in Python cli

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am solving a project in JetBrains Academy. I cannot choose the choice from choices in cli configuration. I try to do the following code but i think it doesn't work, also there are no error messages. I would appreciate if you help me. Thank you in advance.

```
import math
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
option = parser.parse_args()
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
args = parser.parse_args(args)

parser.add_argument("--type", choices=\["diff", "annuity"\], required=False,
help="Add some help text here")
...
if type == "diff":
...
elif type =="annuity":
...
```

I expect to choose from choices which are diff or annuity but i don't figure out how to do it.

Comment: `parse_args` comes last, after all the `add_argument`

Comment: do you realize that `argparse` is meant for parsing arguments provided when running a script from an operating system shell? eg `python myscript.py --type diff`

Comment: `argparse` does not give you an 'input' line or menu, if that's what you are expecting.

Comment: I am actually trying to make the choice i specified, how can i do it?

Comment: It's hard to guess how you imagine a "python cli' appears and works.  I don't know what documentation or tutorial you are working from.  Or how much you understand about programming, and python in particular.  So it's nearly impossible to give more help.

Comment: Why did you add the 'choices' argument after doing the `parse_args()` call(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I believe you want to accomplish:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--type", choices=["diff", "annuity"])
options = parser.parse_args()
print(options)

if options.type == "diff":
    print("It's a diff")
elif options.type == "annuity":
    print("It's an annuity")
```

Sample runs:

```
$ python3 main.py --type annuitx
usage: main.py [-h] [--type {diff,annuity}]
main.py: error: argument --type: invalid choice: 'annuitx' (choose from 'diff', 'annuity')

$ python3 main.py --type diff
Namespace(type='diff')
It's a diff

$ python3 main.py --type annuity
Namespace(type='annuity')
It's an annuity
```